# How to assign a variable type to variables in an object

Tags: javascript, variables, var

Here is the code

```
var m = new Object();
m.p1 = 37.7;
m.p2 = 37.7;
...

function addSubtract(pn){
switch (pn) {
    case 1:
        var amt = prompt("Enter a value");
        if (amt != null)
        {
        m.p1 += amt;
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

Basically when I enter 1, the value of `m.p1` becomes 37.71 instead of 38.7

Then I enter 1.0 and it shows 37.711.0. I figured out it is doing concatenation rather than addition.
I tried to find a way to declare the type but I can't figure out how to use it in a variable in an object.

I am more of a C++ person and there is something obvious that I'm missing here. I just can't find it on Google.

So do I have to assign it a type or is there another way to force an arithmetic addition?

Comment: Since you're adding decimals, look into parseFloat() and toFixed() javascript methods. Search SO for adding decimals. It's a little weird in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `prompt()` will be a string.  If you add a number to a string, the number will be converted to a string and concatenation will be performed.

To convert the string to a float use one of the following:

```
var amt = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a value"));
```

...or:

```
var amt = +prompt("Enter a value");
```

...or:

```
var amt = Number(prompt("Enter a value"));
```

Note that when using `parseFloat()` any extra non-numeric characters at the end will be ignored, but when using the unary `+` method or `Number()` you will get `NaN` if the string has extra characters:

```
> parseFloat('1.0foo')
1
> +'1.0foo'
NaN
> +'1.0'
1
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) the string returned by `prompt()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can force an implicit conversion: `m.p1 += (+amt);`

Comment: I don't think `parseFloat` should ever be suggested for user input...`parseFloat("23.34asdf")` becomes `23.34`, while `Number("23.34asdf")` will be `NaN`. I'd rather be sure the input coming in is taken as-is

Comment: @Ian it all depends on how the OP wants to handle the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (amt != null) m.p1 += Number(amt);
```

this should solve your problems.